# "the variable in a parfor cannot be classified." error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, matlabpool

I am trying to implement a very simple program with parfor but I get some errors. I saw nearly all of the SO questions for a possible duplication but non of them was similar to my question situation. The error I get is :

> Error: The variable
>   log_likelihood_II_with_entropy
>   in a parfor cannot be
>   classified.

My code is written below:

```
em_iterations=10;

users=5;
log_likelihood_II_with_entropy=zeros(users,em_iterations);

parfor u = 1:1:users
      for current_iter=1:1:em_iterations
           log_likelihood_II_with_entropy(u,current_iter)=rand();               
      end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `log_likelihood_II_with_entropy` relies on both the `parfor` index (`u`) and an "inside index" (`current_iter`) it cannot be classified. Every `parfor` iteration is independent from the others and they are not executed in order (that is, `u` will not necessarily go from 1 to `users` in order 1,2,3,4,...,`users`).

My suggestion is to let the single `parfor` iteration (worker) build an entire row of `log_likelihood_II_with_entropy`.

```
parfor u=1:users
    single_row=zeros(1,em_iterations);
    for current_iter=1:1:em_iterations
        single_row(current_iter)=rand();
    end
    log_likelihood_II_with_entropy(u,:)=single_row;
end
```

In this manner every `parfor` task (the `parfor` body itself) will preallocate and evaluate a single row, no matter what the `u` value is. And then it will replace/concatenate such value in the `log_likelihood_II_with_entropy` matrix.

Comment: Or even `rand(1,em_iterations)` :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak oh no :) rand was just an example :D

Comment: @CoderInNetwork I strongly advise you to keep the C in MCVE ([mcve]), it'll make the lives of both answerers and you easier.

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah sure, thanks

Comment: "Since log_likelihood_II_with_entropy relies on both the parfor index (u) and an "inside index" (current_iter) it cannot be classified." , Can you please give me a ref. for this fact?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork of course. There is an entire documentation page by Mathworks regarding variables classification in `parfor` http://it.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html

Answer (score 1):

Parfor loops don't like it when you have 2 variables because it has the potential to get confused. Either use cell arrays to store instead, or else switch the order of your for and parfor loops, as shown below.

```
em_iterations=10;

users=5;
log_likelihood_II_with_entropy=zeros(users,em_iterations);

for u = 1:1:users
      parfor current_iter=1:1:em_iterations
           log_likelihood_II_with_entropy(u,current_iter)=rand();               
      end
end
```

Comment: Full array slices of the form `arr(parindex,:,:)`, however, are allowed. See the answer by Alessiox. That, if applicable, is (almost?) always the fastest solution.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it increases the overhead for communication. Instead of `users` many jobs you now got `users*em_iterations` many jobs increasing the communication overhead.